# Optimal pants decompositions of a hyperbolic surface

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, teichmuller-theory

Let $S$ be a hyperbolic surface, which is not the punctured torus or $4$-holed sphere. I am interested in finding a ``geometrically optimal'' pants decomposition on $S$.

Here is a candidate definition. Given a pants decomposition $P$, order the curves of $P$ *from longest to shortest* (in the hyperbolic metric). Then, pants decompositions $P$ and $P'$ can be compared by comparing the lengths of their curves lexicographically. That is: if the longest curve $c_1$ of $P$ is shorter than the longest curve $c'_1$ of $P'$, then $P$ is better. Or, if $\ell(c_1) = \ell(c'_1)$ and $\ell(c_2) < \ell(c'_2)$, where $c_2, c'_2$ are the second-longest curves of $P$ and $P'$, then $P$ is better. And so on, lexicographically.

With this definition, the induced ordering on pants decompositions becomes a well-ordering. More precisely: given a fixed pants decomposition $P$, there are finitely many curves shorter than the longest curve of $P$, hence finitely many better pants decompositions. In particular, there exists an ``optimal'' decomposition, whose longest curve is no longer than the [Bers constant](http://arxiv.org/abs/0911.5149).

It is clear that optimal decompositions are not necessarily unique (otherwise, the optimal decomposition would never change as we move in Teichmuller space). But if $P$ and $P'$ are both optimal on a given surface, what can be said about how far apart they are? For example: are their shortest curves necessarily disjoint?

Comment: most likely not going to be disjoint shortest curves. Check out Schmutz-Schaller's papers: 
http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1429190
http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1609636

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A pair of optimal pants decompositions $A, B$ need not have disjoint shortest curves.  Here is an example.

Let $S$ be the genus two hyperbolic surface built from four equilateral right-angled hexagons by "doubling".  That is, let $H$ be such a hexagon.  Let $a = 2 \cosh^{-1}(\sqrt{3/2}) = 1.31695\ldots$ denote the side-length of $H$. (See Beardon.) Let $\alpha$ be the union of three non-adjacent sides of $H$ and let $\beta$ be the other three non-adjacent sides.  Doubling $H$ across $\alpha$ gives a pants $P$.  So $\alpha$ gives the seams of $P$ and $\beta$ doubles to give $\partial P$, each component having length $2a$.  Now double across $\beta$ to get $S$.

Let $B = \partial P$ be the double of $\beta$ in $S$.  So $B$ is a pants decomposition of $S$, each curve having length $2a$.  Likewise $A$, the double of $\alpha$, is a pants decomposition.

Claim: All curves of $A$ and $B$ are systoles of $S$.

Proof: Any geodesic in a genus two surface is preserved by the hyperelliptic and so double covers an arc or a loop in the orbifold $O = S^2(2,2,2,2,2,2)$.  In our situation $O$ is the double of $H$ across $\partial H$.  The shortest arc is an edge of $H$.  The shortest loop divides $O$ in half and has length $4\cosh^{-1}(\sqrt{2}) = 3.525494\ldots$. QED

Thus both $A$ and $B$ are optimal, yet every curve of $A$ crosses every curve of $B$.

Answer (score 5):

My paper [arXiv:cs/0604034](http://arxiv.org/abs/cs.CG/0604034) provides an approximately-optimal pants decomposition for the multiply-punctured hyperbolic plane, with a somewhat different optimality condition in which we add the curve lengths rather than compare them lexicographically. I don't know about extensions to other hyperbolic surfaces, though.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look. By the way, it's quite cool to get an answer to a math question in the form of a paper under arXiv:cs/ !